# Adding a button to each row of a list view in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to add two buttons to each row of a list view. And I want to add them in the custom adapter. The two buttons are for edit and delete. The following is my adapter code.

```
public class RoleList extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private String[] name;
    private String[] username;
    private String[] password;
    private String[] role;
    private Activity context;

    public RoleList(Activity context, String[] name, String[] username, String[] password, String[] role)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.role_list,name);
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
        this.username =username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.role_list, null, true);
        TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empname);
        TextView textViewusername = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empusername);
        TextView textViewPass = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emppassword);
        TextView textViewRole = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emprole);


        textViewName.setText(name[position]);
        textViewusername.setText(username[position]);
        textViewPass.setText(password[position]);
        textViewRole.setText(role[position]);



        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Handler for the list:-

```
  public void userRolehandler()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                RoleList roleList = new RoleList(UserRegistration.this,employee_name,emp_username,emp_password,employee_role);

                userList.setAdapter(roleList);
                roleList.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
    }
```

//User Role array

```
 public void userRoleArray() throws JSONException {
        name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        username = editTextUsername.getText().toString();
        password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        emp_role = textRole.getText().toString();

        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.put("name",name);
        jsonobj.put("username",username);
        jsonobj.put("password",password);
        jsonobj.put("emp_role",emp_role);

        rolejson.put(counter,jsonobj);
        counter++;
    }
```

//travRoleArray

```
  public void travRoleArray() throws JSONException {
        response = "{\"result\":" + rolejson.toString() + "}";
        Log.d("RESPONSE",response);
        JSONObject jsonOb = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonOb.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
        try
        {
            for (int i=0; i< result.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jObj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                employee_name[i] = jObj.getString(KEY_NAME);
                emp_username[i] = jObj.getString(KEY_UNAME);
                emp_password[i] = jObj.getString(KEY_PASS);
                employee_role[i] = jObj.getString(KEY_ROLE);
            }

        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(UserRegistration.this, "Contact customer care for assigning more roles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Scenario:

1. User clicks on `add user` button a dialog box opens
2. user enters the required fields and clicks on register
3. a row gets added to the list view.

Screen shots:
[image]
Dialog box:
[image]

Final screen:
[image]

Now I want to add two buttons `edit` and `delete`. To allow the
user to edit and delete the row added to the list view.

Comment: why you don't add 2 `button` to `role_list.xml`

Comment: What your `role_list.xml` file contains. Add that 2 `buttons` to that file.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I tried that but I have arrays each of length 10 which I use to populate the listview.So if I add a button to the role_lis.xml on the first entry itself I get 10 buttons populated in my list.

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/02/muftitouch-listview-multi-click.html look at here

Comment: You have to add two edit/delete button in role_list.xml file and initialize in getView method and you can get its onclickListener event here.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee why you ask `Adding a button to each row`, if you 10 row than you will have 10 button. What do you want?

Comment: I would suggest using a more "native" UX approach - the contextual action mode. It gives you a well known interaction pattern with list items. You long press on an item and a bar pops over the toolbar, containing the actions, available for the specific list item. You can find this type of behaviour in all of Google's apps and in many others. It's better than buttons in a list view IMHO.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh when I add one row with data 9 empty rows are also added so if I add the buttons in the xml the empty rows have the buttons.What I want is when I add the first entry it should have the 2 buttons specific to its row.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee can you share the screenshot that you want to achieve

Comment: @DanailAlexiev thats a good idea but then how will you have control over the list.It would be great if could provide a sample code implementing this scenario.I think it will help a lot of new programmers like me.Thank you.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh yes sure.

Comment: @anup There is a very good tutorial here - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB

Comment: @PhanVănLinh here are the links to the images [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pCSzX.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/drTgK.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rYLGM.png

Comment: @AndroidNewBee, post the code that you use for add new row to the list view.

Comment: @PhanVănLinh please check the updated question.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee sorry, but I want the code that you use to add new user to your list (after use press Add User button)

Comment: @PhanVănLinh I call these 3 methods on click of Register  userRolehandler(); userRoleArray() travRoleArray();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is you should change your `String[] name` to `ArrayList<String> name`

```
public class RoleList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
     //private String[] name;
     private ArrayList<String> name;      

     // it show how many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
     @Override
     public int getCount(){
           return name.size();
     }
}
```

Current you use `String[]`, and the size of it is fix

```
String[] toppings = new String[10];
System.out.println("Hello World"+toppings.length); // will print 10
```

therefore your `ListView` always display 10 items (even some is empty)

But if you use `ArrayList<String>`, the size of list auto change when you add or remove item then your `ListView` will have total row = list size

**OR** if you still want to use `String[]`
You can create a new `int` variable like `realTotalFriends` (it start from 0) and every time you add new user (just increase it by 1)
Then inside `getCount()` you `return realTotalFriends`

```
     int realTotalFriends;
     @Override
     public int getCount(){
           return realTotalFriends;
     }
```

Hope this help

Comment: This is the reason for the 10 rows in the list view.                            String[] employee_name = new String[10];
String[] emp_username = new String[10];
String[] emp_password = new String[10]; String[] employee_role = new String[10];

Comment: @AndroidNewBee yes, after you change `String[]` to `ArrayList<String` you will have one row, if you only have one user

Comment: for (int i=0; i< result.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jObj = result.getJSONObject(i);
                employee_name.get(i) = jObj.getString(KEY_NAME);
                emp_username.get(i) = jObj.getString(KEY_UNAME);
                emp_password.get(i) = jObj.getString(KEY_PASS);
                employee_role.get(i) = jObj.getString(KEY_ROLE);
            } Here I get an error unexpected type.

Comment: @AndroidNewBee you should learn about `ArrayList` first. now the way use are using `ArrayList` is wrong

Comment: I tried the other solution. I set int arrayIndex =1; then inside on click of add user incremented it arrayIndex++; and this is how i initialized it. int arrayIndex =1;

    public int getArrayIndex() {
        return arrayIndex;
    }
    String[] employee_name = new String[getArrayIndex()];
    String[] emp_username = new String[getArrayIndex()];
    String[] emp_password = new String[getArrayIndex()];
    String[] employee_role = new String[getArrayIndex()];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109887/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-androidnewbee).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to re-edit your `R.layout.role_list` to add your button. I assume you know how to add button to layout. After that on your `getView()` method you need to define your buttons and set click listeners for them.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.role_list, null, true);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empname);
    TextView textViewusername = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_empusername);
    TextView textViewPass = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emppassword);
    TextView textViewRole = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tv_emprole);
    Button edit = (Button ) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
    Button delete = (Button ) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.delete_button);


    textViewName.setText(name[position]);
    textViewusername.setText(username[position]);
    textViewPass.setText(password[position]);
    textViewRole.setText(role[position]);

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            yourList.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // May be you can show a popup here
        }
    });


    return listViewItem;
}
```

Hope it works for your needs

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my english.
simply you should add buttons in your "role_list.xml" as you added TextView. then you can add onClickListner on button in your adapter class.
I hope it will help you.